# Batch to FireStore: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have seen several question about this topic. The main reason of this problem is:

*Any collection that you iterate over with foreach may not be modified during iteration.*

In my case, I'm not iterating over the collection which I use in the foreach:

What I want to do is to write to FireStore using the batch.

The code:

```
WriteBatch batch;
FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId);

public async Task publishMessagesPubSub(string message)
{
    try
    {
        PublisherServiceApiClient publisherService = await PublisherServiceApiClient.CreateAsync();
        TopicName topicName = new TopicName(ProjectId, TopicId);
        PublisherClient publisher = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(topicName);

        DateTime pEnqueuedTimeUtc = new DateTime();
        var records = <...>
        if (records != null && records.Length > 0)
        {
            var orderedRecords = records.ToArray();
            string[] records2 = JSONFormatter.FormatToJson(orderedRecords);
            foreach (string record in records2)
            //Parallel.ForEach(records2, async record =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() => publisher.PublishAsync(record));
                var frameFormatted = JSONtoDict(record);
                await Task.Run(() => StorageMessagesInFireStoreDocumentBatch(frameFormatted, "test"));

                //await publisher.ShutdownAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
            }
            //);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        WriteLogEntry("publishMessagesPubSub: Message:" + exc.Message);
    }
}
```

And the method where the collection is modified:

```
private async Task StorageMessagesInFireStoreDocumentBatch(Dictionary<string, object> data, string FireStoreCollection)
{
    try

    {
        if (contadorBatch==0)
            batch = db.StartBatch();
        contadorBatch = contadorBatch + 1;
        CollectionReference FramesCollection = db.Collection(FireStoreCollection);
        DocumentReference   document = FramesCollection.Document();
        batch.Set(document, data);

        if (contadorBatch >= 450)
        {
            contadorBatch = 0;
            var future= batch.CommitAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Debug.WriteLine("future.Count(): Message:" + future.Count());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("StorageMessagesInFireStoreDocumentBatch: Message:" + exc.Message);
    }
}
```

**The result**

Sometimes the data are written without any problem and other I have this exception:

*StorageMessagesInFireStoreDocumentBatch: Message:Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.*

How I should do it to add element to the FireStore collection inside the foreach loop?

---

> EXTRA

First approach:

```
 public async Task publishMessagesPubSub(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                PublisherServiceApiClient publisherService = await PublisherServiceApiClient.CreateAsync();
                TopicName topicName = new TopicName(ProjectId, TopicId);
                PublisherClient publisher = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(topicName);                
                //Dictionary<string, object> frameFormatted;
                WriteBatch batch = db.StartBatch();
                DateTime pEnqueuedTimeUtc = new DateTime();
                var records = <...>;
                if (records != null && records.Length > 0)
                {
                    var orderedRecords = records.ToArray();
                    string[] records2 = JSONFormatter.FormatToJson(orderedRecords);
                    //foreach (string record in records2)
                    Parallel.ForEach(records2, async record =>
                    {
                        await Task.Run(() => publisher.PublishAsync(record));
                        await Task.Run(() => StorageMessagesInFireStoreDocumentBatch(JSONtoDict(record), document, batch));                       
                    }
                    );
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                WriteLogEntry("publishMessagesPubSub: Message:" + exc.Message);
            }
        }


private async Task StorageMessagesInFireStoreDocumentBatch(Dictionary<string, object> data, DocumentReference document, WriteBatch batch)
{
    try
    {
        batch.Set(document, data);
        var future= await  batch.CommitAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("future.Count(): Message:" + future.Count());

    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("StorageMessagesInFireStoreDocumentBatch: Message:" + exc.Message);
        //WriteLogEntry("StorageMessagesInFireStoreDocumentBatch: Message:" + exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got multiple tasks calling `StorageMessagesInFireStoreDocumentBatch` at the same time. Basically those are modifying the batch (by calling `batch.Set`) and implicitly iterating over it (by calling `CommitAsync()`) at the same time. It's probably simplest to use locking to avoid this - make sure that only one task is doing anything with the batch at a time. (Note that after committing the batch, you should probably be starting a new one by calling `StartBatch` again.)

Comment: More generally - I would probably create the batches synchronously. You can *send* them asynchronously, but I don't think there's any benefit in creating this many tasks.

Comment: Thank you Jon.I have tried doing synchronously but I suppose I didn't do it well because I had the same exception sometimes. So I modified the code to do a microbatch. I added the code to the main post.

Comment: You haven't made any changes to the question...

Comment: You are very fast! ;P I was doing

Comment: You're still modifying a single batch asynchronously. That's simply not going to work - you can't commit in one thread while you're adding to the batch in another thread.